# Google sheets combine query syntax

Tags: google-sheets

I have this as my first query
=Query({'Cut request '!A2:S;'Out sent '!A2:S},"Select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col3,Col10,Col13,Col17,Col19 Where Col4 is not null",0)

I want to combine both with this
QUERY(leadlist!A2:Q,"Select I,M Where A is not null",0)

I tried doing this but got an "Formula parse error"
=Query(ARRAYFORMULA({'Connection request '!A2:S;'Message sent '!A2:S},"Select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col3,Col10,Col13,Col17,Col19 Where Col4 is not null",0};QUERY(leadgen!A2:Q,"Select I,M Where A is not null",0)}))

I can not figure out how to combine both to make it works

Please any help. Thanks in advance, appreciated.

Comment: When you build multiple blocks of data into an array, one rule must be followed - the size of the blocks to be built must be the same. In your case, I can assume that the number of rows resulting from the first query does not match the number of rows resulting from the second query. _But this is only a guess. If you shared your list, or made an example or at least showed some screenshots, then I think the right solution would be found much faster_

Comment: Yes your are correct all sheets has different number of Rows. I want to attached my file here but I don't know how? In fact I am trying to run this query In ={Query({'Cut request '!A2:S;'Out sent '!A2:S},"Select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col3,Col10,Col13,Col17,Col19 Where Col4 is not null",0);QUERY(leadlist!A2:Q,"Select  A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H Where A is not null",0)} but ir returns an error "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."  please any help how i am going to fix then thanks in advance @Sergey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With exactly the same number of columns, it will be ok (as Sergey said). For instance :

```
={Query({'Cut request '!A2:S;'Out sent '!A2:S},"Select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col3,Col10,Col13,Col17,Col19 Where Col4 is not null",0);QUERY(leadlist!A2:Q,"Select  A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H Where A is not null",0)}
```

Comment: thanks @Mike Steelson for the kind help but it returns an "Error In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows."

Comment: Here is the spreadsheet I used to test https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1klFdryDzsPmbksykZwMSdPLSIH-4YD3TWFLaEgrRs5c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for your kind help appreciated @Mike Steelson